# Disable gzip compression only for https connections on nginx

Tags: nginx, https, server

Having a server block that should serve content both for http and https :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  include snippets/certificate.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
  root ...
}
```

Is it possible configure the gzip compression off only for the https connection in the same server block, or do i have to slipt them ?

**EDIT:**

Actually could be done checking the request scheme inside the location block and set gzip to off if is equal to https:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  include snippets/certificate.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  location / {
      if ($scheme = "https") {
          gzip off;
      }
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  ...
}
```

problem is it seem safe only use **rewrite** and **return** statement inside if block https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not possible

> Syntax:   gzip on | off;
>
> Default:
>
> gzip off;
>
> Context:  http, server, location, if in location

As you can see it can be used only in these blocks `http, server, location, if in location`. And it doesn't allow any parameters for the value

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid value "$gzip_flag" in "gzip" directive, it must be "on" or "off" in /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:15
```

So you have to split your servers into two. But since rest of your stuff will be common, you can put everything in a include file. Include that file in both server locations